# Strings in JPA Criteria API Queries

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have a question about comparing String value (it is a number stored in db as a nvarchar) with a number in JPA Criteria API. Is there any possibility to do this? I've tried with method .as(Class), but it didn't work. It always comparing two Strings, not two numbers.

EDIT:

I have a column in table (name -> fieldValue). It stores numbers, but in text format nvarchar. I want to make predicate in JPA CriteriaApi that give me rows from this table, in which fieldValue is greater than some value. I tried:

```
criteriaBuilder.gt(c.get("fieldValue").as(Long.class), someValue);
```

but id didn't work

Comment: "It did not work". That tells people a lot. Never thought that they would like to know what SQL was generated, or what exception you got?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to annotate the property with a `Converter` class. In this way, the Java `Entity` field is a `Long`, but the database column is a `String`.

```
@Converter
public class LongToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Long,String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Long attribute) {
        return attribute.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public Long convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return Long.parseLong(dbData);
    }
}
```

With this, the `CriteriaQuery` is pretty straight forward.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Entity> q = cb.createQuery(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> l = q.from(Entity.class);
q.select(l).where(cb.equal(l.get("fieldValue"), 12344321L));
Entity r = em.createQuery(q).getSingleResult();
System.out.println(r);
```